# Partial class generated from xsd

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have this xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="mfp:anaf:dgti:d300:declaratie:v3" targetNamespace="mfp:anaf:dgti:d300:declaratie:v3" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.02" xml:lang="ro">
<xs:element name="declaratie300" type="Declaratie300Type"/>
<xs:complexType name="Declaratie300Type">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
<xs:attribute name="luna" type="IntInt1_12SType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="an" type="IntInt2012_2100SType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="bifa_interne" type="IntInt0_1SType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="nume_declar" type="Str75" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="prenume_declar" type="Str75" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="functie_declar" type="Str50" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="cui" type="CuiSType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="den" type="Str200" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="adresa" type="Str1000" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="telefon" type="Str15"/>
<xs:attribute name="fax" type="Str15"/>
<xs:attribute name="mail" type="Email200SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="banca" type="Str50" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="cont" type="Str50" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="caen" type="Str_listaCaenSType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="tip_decont" type="Str_listaDecontSType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="pro_rata" type="DblGen3_2_L_0d0_100d0SType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="bifa_cereale" type="Str_listaDaNuSType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="solicit_ramb" type="Str_listaDaNuSType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="nr_evid" type="IntStr23SType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="totalPlata_A" type="IntNeg18SType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="R1_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R2_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R3_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R3_1_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R4_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R5_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R5_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R5_1_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R5_1_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R6_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R6_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R7_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R7_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R7_1_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R7_1_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R8_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R8_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R9_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R9_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R10_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R10_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R11_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R11_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R12_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R12_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R13_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R14_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R15_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R16_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R16_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R17_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R17_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R18_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R18_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R18_1_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R18_1_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R19_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R19_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R20_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R20_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R20_1_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R20_1_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R21_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R21_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R22_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R22_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R23_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R23_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R24_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R24_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R25_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R25_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R26_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R26_1_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R27_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R27_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R28_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R29_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R30_1" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R30_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R31_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R32_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R33_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R34_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R35_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R36_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R37_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R38_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R39_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R40_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R41_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="R42_2" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="nr_facturi" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="baza" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="tva" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="valoare_a" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="tva_a" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="valoare_b" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
<xs:attribute name="tva_b" type="IntNeg15SType"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="IntInt1_12SType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="12"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="IntInt2012_2100SType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:minInclusive value="2012"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="2100"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="IntInt0_1SType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str75">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="75"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str50">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="50"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="CuiSType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:token">
<xs:pattern value="[1-9]\d{1,9}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str200">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="200"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str1000">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="1000"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str15">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="15"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Email200SType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:token">
<xs:maxLength value="200"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str_listaCaenSType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="4"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0111"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0112"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0113"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0114"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0115"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0116"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0119"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0121"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0122"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0123"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0124"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0125"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0126"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0127"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0128"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0129"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0130"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0141"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0142"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0143"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0144"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0145"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0146"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0147"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0149"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0150"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0161"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0162"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0163"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0164"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0170"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0210"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0220"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0230"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0240"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0311"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0312"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0321"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0322"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0510"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0520"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0610"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0620"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0710"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0721"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0729"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0811"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0812"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0891"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0892"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0893"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0899"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0910"/>
<xs:enumeration value="0990"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1011"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1012"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1013"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1020"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1031"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1032"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1039"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1041"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1042"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1051"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1052"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1061"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1062"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1071"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1072"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1073"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1081"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1082"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1083"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1084"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1085"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1086"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1089"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1091"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1092"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1101"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1102"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1103"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1104"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1105"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1106"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1107"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1200"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1310"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1320"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1330"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1391"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1392"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1393"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1394"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1395"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1396"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1399"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1411"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1412"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1413"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1414"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1419"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1420"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1431"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1439"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1511"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1512"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1520"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1610"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1621"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1622"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1623"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1624"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1629"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1711"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1712"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1721"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1722"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1723"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1724"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1729"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1811"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1812"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1813"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1814"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1820"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1910"/>
<xs:enumeration value="1920"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2011"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2012"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2013"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2014"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2015"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2016"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2017"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2020"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2030"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2041"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2042"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2051"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2052"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2053"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2059"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2060"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2110"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2120"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2211"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2219"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2221"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2222"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2223"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2229"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2311"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2312"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2313"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2314"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2319"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2320"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2331"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2332"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2341"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2342"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2343"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2344"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2349"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2351"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2352"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2361"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2362"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2363"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2364"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2365"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2369"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2370"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2391"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2399"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2410"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2420"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2431"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2432"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2433"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2434"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2441"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2442"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2443"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2444"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2445"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2446"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2451"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2452"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2453"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2454"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2511"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2512"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2521"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2529"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2530"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2540"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2550"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2561"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2562"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2571"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2572"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2573"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2591"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2592"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2593"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2594"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2599"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2611"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2612"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2620"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2630"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2640"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2651"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2652"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2660"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2670"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2680"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2711"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2712"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2720"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2731"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2732"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2733"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2740"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2751"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2752"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2790"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2811"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2812"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2813"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2814"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2815"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2821"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2822"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2823"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2824"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2825"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2829"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2830"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2841"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2849"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2891"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2892"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2893"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2894"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2895"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2896"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2899"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2910"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2920"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2931"/>
<xs:enumeration value="2932"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3011"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3012"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3020"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3030"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3040"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3091"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3092"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3099"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3101"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3102"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3103"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3109"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3211"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3212"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3213"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3220"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3230"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3240"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3250"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3291"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3299"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3311"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3312"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3313"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3314"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3315"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3316"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3317"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3319"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3320"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3511"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3512"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3513"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3514"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3521"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3522"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3523"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3530"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3600"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3700"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3811"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3812"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3821"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3822"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3831"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3832"/>
<xs:enumeration value="3900"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4110"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4120"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4211"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4212"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4213"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4221"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4222"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4291"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4299"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4311"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4312"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4313"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4321"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4322"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4329"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4331"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4332"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4333"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4334"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4339"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4391"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4399"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4511"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4519"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4520"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4531"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4532"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4540"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4611"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4612"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4613"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4614"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4615"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4616"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4617"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4618"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4619"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4621"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4622"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4623"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4624"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4631"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4632"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4633"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4634"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4635"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4636"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4637"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4638"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4639"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4641"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4642"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4643"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4644"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4645"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4646"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4647"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4648"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4649"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4651"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4652"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4661"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4662"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4663"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4664"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4665"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4666"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4669"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4671"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4672"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4673"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4674"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4675"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4676"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4677"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4690"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4711"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4719"/>
<xs:enumeration value="4721"/>
<xs:enumeration value="9820"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str_listaDecontSType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="1"/>
<xs:enumeration value="L"/>
<xs:enumeration value="T"/>
<xs:enumeration value="S"/>
<xs:enumeration value="A"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="DblGen3_2_L_0d0_100d0SType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:double">
<xs:pattern value="\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,2})?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="100.0"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str_listaDaNuSType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="1"/>
<xs:enumeration value="D"/>
<xs:enumeration value="N"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="IntStr23SType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="99999999999999999999999"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="IntNeg18SType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:minInclusive value="-999999999999999999"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="999999999999999999"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="IntNeg15SType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:minInclusive value="-999999999999999"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="999999999999999"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And i want to generate a C#/VB class from it. but when I run the:

```
xsd  1.xsd /c
```

I only get a partial class

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="mfp:anaf:dgti:d300:declaratie:v3")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("declaratie300", Namespace="mfp:anaf:dgti:d300:declaratie:v3", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Declaratie300Type {
}
```

The source of the XSD is : https://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Anaf/Declaratii_R/AplicatiiDec/d300_v3.xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the schema to use the simplified notation for the element (defined as equivalent [by the w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#emptyContent))

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="mfp:anaf:dgti:d300:declaratie:v3" targetNamespace="mfp:anaf:dgti:d300:declaratie:v3" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.02" xml:lang="ro">
    <xs:element name="declaratie300" type="Declaratie300Type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Declaratie300Type">
        <xs:attribute name="luna" type="IntInt1_12SType" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="an" type="IntInt2012_2100SType" use="required"/>
        .
        .
        .
```

then the class can be generated fine.